# How to extend an existing custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I have a custom element, called `x-foo`. I would like to extend it, and create an `x-foo-extended` element, but it doesn't works. I get this error:

Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type `'x-foo-extended'`. The tag name specified in 'extends' is a custom element name. Use inheritance instead.

```
    var xFooExtendedProto = Object.create(xFoo.prototype);

    xFooExtendedProto.someCustomFunc = function() {
        // ...
    };

    xFooExtended = document.registerElement('x-foo-extended', {
        prototype: xFooExtendedProto,
        extends: 'x-foo'
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#dfn-definition-construction-algorithm) , this is not permitted. 
From the spec:
"If BASE does not exist or is an interface for a custom element, set ERROR
to InvalidName and stop."

Source: As described by the person who implemented custom elements in Chrome
https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014OctDec/0155.html