# Custom Polymer element with table as a base element

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I am trying to create two custom Polymer elements: tree-grid and tree-grid-item. The tree-grid would be an empty table that would accept tree-grid-item elements. Something like:

```
  <dom-module id="tree-grid">
     <template>
        <style>
          :host {
            display: block;
          }
        </style>
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <content></content>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </template>
      <!-- javascript -->
      </dom-module>
```

and the tree-grid-item is a table row with an icon:

```
   <dom-module id="tree-grid-item">
      <template>
        <style>
          :host {
            display: block;
          }
          .grid-item {
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }​
            </style>

      <tr class="grid-item">
        <td><iron-icon icon="icons:chevron-right"></iron-icon></td>
          <td>
            <content></content>
          </td>
         </tr>
       </template>
      <!-- javascript -->
    </dom-module>
```

The issue that I am facing is that the items are not added inside the table when I test the elements:

```
<tree-grid>
     <tree-grid-item>element 1</tree-grid-item>
     <tree-grid-item>element 2</tree-grid-item>
 </tree-grid>
```

gives a Dom structure like:

[image]

Obviously, the tree-grid-items should be inside the table, but Polymer just refuses to put them there. is this a common Polymer issue? is there a way around it ? Thanks

Comment: no surprise, html insists on the parents of TR and TD tags. use `<table is=` instead

Comment: in the present case I would say: use `<tr is=` instead.

Comment: it did not work out unfortunately

Comment: did you add the `extends: 'tr'` property in the module declaration?

Comment: this question is about the same type of custom element here, but without polymer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41585527/

Comment: Thanks @Supersharp, I tried with extends as well, it does not make it any better. I think I will do with divs instead of table