# Creating a custom table row

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am trying to create a custom table row but having difficulty getting it to behave properly.  I've tried the two below methods and they give bizarre results.  I realize that this is very easy to to without custom elements but this is a small example of a much larger project.  What can I change to achieve the desired result?

```js
class customTableRow extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    
    this.tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
    

    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = "RowTitle";
    this.tableRow.appendChild(td);
    
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    td2.innerText = "RowContent";
    td2.colSpan = 4;
    this.tableRow.appendChild(td2);

    shadow.appendChild(this.tableRow);
  }
  
}

customElements.define('custom-tr', customTableRow);

//Attempt 2
var newTr = new customTableRow;
document.getElementById('table2Body').appendChild(newTr);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span>Attempt 1:</span>
<table>
  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <custom-tr />
  </tbody>
  
</table>

<hr>

<span>Attempt 2:</span>
<table id="table2">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody id="table2Body">
<!--     It should append here -->
  </tbody>
  
</table>

<hr>

<span>This is how I want it to look:</span>
<table id="table2">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Title</td>
      <td colspan="4">Row Content</td>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `<table>` element and its subcomponents `<tbody>`, `<tr>` require a very specific syntax. For example, only `<tr>` elements are authorized as children of `<tbody>`.

Therefore you cannot define a  element and insert it in `<tbody>` or `<table>`. If you do that it will be moved outside of the `<table>` at parsing. Hence the display of your first example (look the code in the Dev Tools).

Instead you should define a *customized tag* instead like in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41587119/4600982).

Or you should redefine a complete custom table structure with `<custom-table>`, `<custom-tbody>`... like in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592251/4600982).

Also, you should use closing tag `<custom-tr></custom-tr>`, and insert your CSS rule in the Shadow DOM if you want it to by applied inside it.

Comment: Hmm, I am going to have to think on this and do some more reading.  I am fairly new to web dev and this may be something bigger than I can chew.  If it is possible, would it be easier to create a new class by extending a `tr` class?

Comment: How can this be done?  Looking around it seems I could extend `HTMLTableRowElement` but I have not been able to find a way to code this without an `Illegal Constructor` error being thrown.

Comment: As an example, Solution 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43086994/4600982) defines a customized built-in element v1 with the help of a polyfill

Comment: Can this be achieved with vanilla js, or do I need that WebReflection script?

Comment: You'll need that polyfill or the one from [webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) because [it is not implemented yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988275/4600982).

Comment: As an alternative, consider using the much simpler element-behaviors package: https://github.com/infamous/element-behaviors. It allows you to place "behaviors", which have the same life cycle methods as custom elements, onto any elements, without the caveats of custom elements (like that they don't work with tables).