# <th> as slotted node

Tags: ecmascript-6, custom-element

I have defined a shadow template as follows:

```
  <table id="overviewbox-loadingbox">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <slot name="table-header"></slot>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <div id="loadingbox"></div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The users are supposed to supply their own `<th>`s by something like:

```
  <th slot="table-header" data-column_name="description">describing here</th>
```

However this doesn't work. As soon as I change `<th>` to `<span>`, with all other things unchanged, the slotted node shows up. Is this because there is some undocumented quirks about using `<th>` and `<slot>` together? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a custom table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764553/creating-a-custom-table-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<tr>` and `<tbody>` have a very limited set of allowed children. So you may not be able to do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it.

But...

You can use `<div>` and `<span>` and just set their CSS to be:

```
display: table-row-group;
display: table-header-group;
display: table-footer-group;
display: table-row;
display: table-cell;
display: table-column-group;
display: table-column;
```

Then there is no limitation of children.

---

You can also use the newer [Customized built-in elements](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#creating-a-customized-built-in-element) paradigm like `<td is="my-td"></td>`:

Comment: So the problem is `<slot>` not being allowed in `<tr>`? Then why does using a `<span>` instead of `<th>` work?

Comment: If you use `<div>` and `<span>` instead of `<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, etc. then you can place `<slot>` in your code. But then you have to be careful to not allow `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc in the children that will end up in the `<slot>`