# Extend HTMLSelectElement

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, custom-element

Recently, I tried to extends a HTMLSelectElement instead of creating a brand new element, for semantic and accessibility reasons, i.e :

```
 let customSelect = function () {
  customElements.define(
    "custom-select",
    class CustomSelect extends HTMLSelectElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      test
      `;
      }
    },
    { extends: "select" }
  );
};

export default customSelect;
```

It returned the following error : custom-select.js:6 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'attachShadow' on 'Element': This element does not support attachShadow.

*Ok, that was predictable.*

Since I can't work with shadow-dom, my question is *what is the best solution from there?* 
So far, I can imagine:

- Working directly with the innerHTML of this component.
- Creating that brand new element to work with shadow dom.
- Overwriting the existing shadow? (If such method could possibly exist).

So what's in your mind is the most simple and 'SEO-friendly' solution? 
nb : *The solution must be custom-element-based*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Working directly with the innerHTML of this component.

It's the "most simple and 'SEO-friendly' solution".

---

> Creating that brand new element to work with shadow dom.

Potentialy the most user-friendly as you can define an enhanced UI.

---

> Overwriting the existing shadow?

Not possible. It is read-only.

---

[Example of `<select>` enhanced with Custom Elements here in this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43086994/4600982).